# contacts count and users count are different between Graph API and outlook website

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api

Firstly, I used Microsoft Graph API `/me/contacts` to get all contacts, and I got 6000+ contacts' info. But when I login `https://outlook.office.com/owa/?path=/people` and visited [Your Contacts] page to compared the contact number, there are only 5000+ contacts.

Secondly, same problem in users count, I used Microsoft Graph API `/users` to get all users' info, and I got 5000+. But when I go to `https://outlook.office.com/owa/?path=/people` and visited [Directory > All Users], the number is only 4000+

I guessed outlook had filter some contacts, but I don't know the the filtering rules.

I wanted to solve this problem, but I don't know how.

So can someone tell me the filtering rules or can I use Microsoft Graph API token to fetch datas from Outlook API directly?

Answer (score 0):

> So can someone tell me the filtering rules or

This answer need the guy from outlook team. Ignore now.

> can I use Microsoft Graph API token to fetch data from Outlook API
>   directly?
>   No. Graph API token not the same as the pure Outlook API.

For the count issue, based on your project requirement to decide which to use. In other words, you can use your own filtering rules. In my opinion, use  the data have more records, and then filter.